# Как исключить стоимость доставки из заказа в компоненте sale.order.ajax

Tags: битрикс

Есть необходимость выставлять счет покупателю без стоимости доставки. На странице оформления заказа используется компонент sale.order.ajax последней версии.
Удалось отловить момент сохранения заказа и даже изменить итоговую цену, но заказ не сохраняется. В черновой версии пробую делать так:
ловлю событие "OnSaleComponentOrderCreated", скармливаю ему свой метод, в котором получаю объект заказа и отнимаю стоимость доставки:

```
$price = $order->getField('PRICE') - $order->getDeliveryPrice();
$order->setField('PRICE', $price);
$order->save();
```

но после общая стоимость заказа не меняется, подскажите как изменить итоговую цену заказа, важно, чтобы в счет попадала цена без доставки. Счет может выставляться, как по безналу, так и на оплату яндекс-деньгами, либо банковской картой.

Answer (score 1):

Так в `Маркетинг → Товарный маркетиг → Правила работы с корзиной`. Там можно настроить правило делать 100% скидку на заказ при определеных условиях. У меня был пример тип плательщика "Юр лицо" и чек на сумму больше или равно 6000 доставка бесплатная.